# Spacy can't be installed in virtualenv which is created with pypy

Tags: python, pypy, spacy

I created virtualenv(pypy as compiler).

Now when I tried to install Spacy using pip I get below error.

```
Failed to build spacy thinc
Installing collected packages: thinc, ujson, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, regex, webencodings, html5lib, wcwidth, ftfy, spacy
  Running setup.py install for thinc ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/azar-4893/Python_Venv/falconpypy/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/y1/npxxtb7n3k5d2mb7_5pwsr1xr6pvqq/T/pip-build-F0nppE/thinc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/y1/npxxtb7n3k5d2mb7_5pwsr1xr6pvqq/T/pip-Thl94z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/azar-4893/Python_Venv/falconpypy/include/site/python2.7/thinc:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'thinc.linalg' extension
    gcc -pthread -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/Users/azar-4893/Python_Venv/falconpypy/include -I/private/var/folders/y1/npxxtb7n3k5d2mb7_5pwsr1xr6pvqq/T/pip-build-F0nppE/thinc/include -I/Users/azar-4893/Python_Venv/falconpypy/include -c thinc/linalg.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/thinc/linalg.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
    clang: error: no such file or directory: 'thinc/linalg.cpp'
    clang: error: no input files
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/azar-4893/Python_Venv/falconpypy/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/y1/npxxtb7n3k5d2mb7_5pwsr1xr6pvqq/T/pip-build-F0nppE/thinc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/y1/npxxtb7n3k5d2mb7_5pwsr1xr6pvqq/T/pip-Thl94z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/azar-4893/Python_Venv/falconpypy/include/site/python2.7/thinc" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/y1/npxxtb7n3k5d2mb7_5pwsr1xr6pvqq/T/pip-build-F0nppE/thinc/
```

Is there a way to install spacy for pypy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spacy` uses a c-extensions module called `thinc` to do its heavy lifting in C. The latest PyPy cannot install `thinc`, there are multiple issues blocking its installation. [Here](https://github.com/explosion/thinc/issues/31) is one on thinc, and [this](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/blob/master/cytoolz/functoolz.pyx#L454) as yet unsupported call to `PyFrozenSet_New` in cytoolz

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, try this--

```
CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' pip install spacy==2.0.12 thinc==6.10.3 google-compute-engine https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref-models/releases/download/en_coref_md-3.0.0/en_coref_md-3.0.0.tar.gz
```